# No more spool space in username

Tags: sql-server, odbc, teradata

In sql managment studio I'm writing queries using 'openquery'.
I have a link server to teradata. I'm running a code and I'm getting the error:

```
"MSDASQL" for linked server "teradata" returned message:
"[Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver][Teradata database] No more spool space in username"
```

How can I fix it? When I'm running it on sas connection to teradata it works good. Why does in sql server/sql managment studio it keeps throwing me this message? the errors are belong to teradata and both the dbms (sas and sql managment studio) are connecting to the teradata database.

thank's for your help.

Comment: Perhaps this post on the teradata site will help https://community.teradata.com/t5/Database/No-More-Spool-Space-issue-encountered/td-p/33535

Comment: It means that your username has no more spool space. Spool space is the space used while executing your query to store intermediate result sets and the final result set as the DB is responding to your client. Either you need to rewrite your query or you need to request more spool space be added to complete the query.

Comment: Does SAS connect through ODBC or through the native client? Here might be the difference. Also, check that you have the same username in both connections by running select user; before the main query.